# Convert observablecollection of paths into collection of filenames

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have observable collection filled with paths to files e.g.:

```
C:/Documents/1.png
```

and I would like to convert them all into filenames and use as itemsSource for my listbox but observablecollection doesn't have convertAll method

```
ObservableCollection<string> InputEpisodes = new ObservableCollection<String>();

filesFoundListBox.ItemsSource = InputEpisodes.ConvertAll(x => Path.GetFileName(x));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Binding Converter that converts from file path to file name:

```
public class FileNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Path.GetFileName((string)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it in your ListBox like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FileNameConverter x:Key="FileNameConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

...
<ListBox x:Name="filesFoundListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FileNameConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You can now directly assign the `InputEpisodes` collection to the ListBox's ItemsSource:

```
filesFoundListBox.ItemsSource = InputEpisodes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, while the answer using a binding converter is good, if you might need more information from a file, it might be preferable to create a class `FileInformation` that would contains required properties like `FileName`, `Path`, `FileSize`...

That way you can more easily have different presentations for your list box and you would also be able to keep original path which might be useful later if you need to get back the information (maybe, you have multiple copies of a given file name if you allows files from multiple directories).